# What's the event for changing Severity on screen Case (ScreenID: CR306000)?

Tags: acumatica

After I customized the code below and I want to update SLA by AssignDateTime. But with the Severity changed then my SLA has changed to get datetime from createdDateTime also. I think it should have other event that need to customize.

```cs
protected virtual void CRCase_RowUpdated(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e, PXRowUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
{
    if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
        InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
    var row = e.Row as CRCase;
    var oldRow = e.OldRow as CRCase;
    CRCaseExt rowExt = PXCache<CRCase>.GetExtension<CRCaseExt>(row);

    if (row == null || oldRow == null) return;

    if (row.OwnerID == null)
    {
        row.AssignDate = null;
        row.SLAETA = null;
    }
    else if (oldRow.OwnerID == null)
    {
        row.AssignDate = PXTimeZoneInfo.Now;
        if (row == null || row.AssignDate == null) return;

        if (row.ClassID != null && row.Severity != null)
        {
            var severity = (CRClassSeverityTime)PXSelect<CRClassSeverityTime,
                            Where<CRClassSeverityTime.caseClassID, Equal<Required<CRClassSeverityTime.caseClassID>>,
                            And<CRClassSeverityTime.severity, Equal<Required<CRClassSeverityTime.severity>>>>>
                            .Select(Base, row.ClassID, row.Severity);
            if (severity != null && severity.TimeReaction != null)
            {
                row.SLAETA = ((DateTime)row.AssignDate).AddMinutes((int)severity.TimeReaction);
            }
        }
        if (row.Severity != null && row.ContractID != null)
        {
            var template = (Contract)PXSelect<Contract, Where<Contract.contractID, Equal<Required<CRCase.contractID>>>>.Select(Base, row.ContractID);
            if (template == null) return;
            var sla = (ContractSLAMapping)PXSelect<ContractSLAMapping,
                    Where<ContractSLAMapping.severity, Equal<Required<CRCase.severity>>,
                    And<ContractSLAMapping.contractID, Equal<Required<CRCase.contractID>>>>>
                    .Select(Base, row.Severity, template.TemplateID);
            if (sla != null && sla.Period != null)
            {
                row.SLAETA = ((DateTime)row.AssignDate).AddMinutes((int)sla.Period);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SLAETA field is decorated with PXFormulaAttribute to raise FieldDefaulting event every time change is made to one of the following fields:

- CRCase.contractID
- CRCase.severity
- CRCase.caseClassID

  ```
  public partial class CRCase : IBqlTable, IAssign, IAttributeSupport, IPXSelectable
  {
      ...

      #region SLAETA
      public abstract class sLAETA : IBqlField { }

      [PXDBDate(PreserveTime = true, DisplayMask = "g")]
      [PXUIField(DisplayName = "SLA")]
      [PXFormula(typeof(Default<CRCase.contractID, CRCase.severity, CRCase.caseClassID>))]
      public virtual DateTime? SLAETA { get; set; }
      #endregion

      ...

  }
  ```

It’s a way better to only customize CRCase_SLAETA_FieldDefaulting handler in the CRCaseMaint BLC extension instead of implementing CRCase_RowUpdated:

```
public class CRCaseMaint : PXGraph<CRCaseMaint, CRCase>
{
    ...

    protected virtual void CRCase_SLAETA_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
    {
        CRCase row = e.Row as CRCase;
        if (row == null || row.CreatedDateTime == null) return;

        if (row.ClassID != null && row.Severity != null)
        {
            var severity = (CRClassSeverityTime)PXSelect<CRClassSeverityTime,
                                                    Where<CRClassSeverityTime.caseClassID, Equal<Required<CRClassSeverityTime.caseClassID>>,
                                                    And<CRClassSeverityTime.severity, Equal<Required<CRClassSeverityTime.severity>>>>>.
                                                    Select(this, row.ClassID, row.Severity);
            if (severity != null && severity.TimeReaction != null)
            {
                e.NewValue = ((DateTime)row.CreatedDateTime).AddMinutes((int)severity.TimeReaction);
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }

        if (row.Severity != null && row.ContractID != null)
        {
            var template = (Contract)PXSelect<Contract, Where<Contract.contractID, Equal<Required<CRCase.contractID>>>>.Select(this, row.ContractID);
            if (template == null) return;

            var sla = (ContractSLAMapping)PXSelect<ContractSLAMapping,
                                              Where<ContractSLAMapping.severity, Equal<Required<CRCase.severity>>,
                                              And<ContractSLAMapping.contractID, Equal<Required<CRCase.contractID>>>>>.
                                              Select(this, row.Severity, template.TemplateID);
            if (sla != null && sla.Period != null)
            {
                e.NewValue = ((DateTime)row.CreatedDateTime).AddMinutes((int)sla.Period);
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: So if I want to update when the changing of Severity,  I should customize the same coding on CRCase_RowUpdated event right?

Comment: FieldDefaulting is raised for the SLAETA field every time CRCase.severity gets modified due to the implementation of PXFormulaAttribute decorating it. To update SLAETA “when the changing of Severity”, you should only override CRCase_SLAETA_FieldDefaulting and assign new value to e.NewValue, no additional handlers, like CRCase_RowUpdated, are required to accomplish your task.

Comment: Anyways, how can I set the Max value and Min Value of DateTime with BQL structure?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of a Min DateTime Value in BQL structure?

Comment: I'm not sure but if I want to get the Date time like 08/03/2016 12:00 when I create new case, don't want it to get the value of time from the current time.

Answer (score -1):

You can either use the FieldUpdated Event or in the row updated event you can look for the change of your field.

Eg:  row.Severity != oldRow.Severity

Comment: Yes, I've already use that event but I used the same coding as CRCase_SLAETA_FieldDefaulting.